# How to get the next business date in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Business days are Monday through Friday.

Given I have a datetime field `scheduled_for`, how can I find the next business date and return that in a column alias?

I've tried something from another SO answer but it doesn't work as intended.

```
EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM v.scheduled_for)::integer) % 7 as next_business_day,
```

Error:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3:  EXTRACT(ISODOW FROM v.scheduled_for)::integer % 7)  as next...

                                                      ^
```

Edit:

Thanks for the suggestions, I've attempted this:

```
SELECT
    v.id AS visit_id,
    (IF extract(''dow'' from v.scheduled_for) = 0 THEN
        return v.scheduled_for + 1::integer;
    ELSIF extract(''dow'' from v.scheduled_for) = 6 THEN
        return v.scheduled_for - 1::integer;
    ELSE
        return v.scheduled_for;
    ) as next_business_day, 
    '' as invoice_ref_code,
```

The error I get is:

```
Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ) as next_business_day, 
    ^
```

Comment: Count `(` and `)`. Same number?

Comment: This article might give you the code you need:  http://www.accountingenhancements.com/filetree/PostgreSQL/psql_business_day.html

Comment: "Business Day" data manipulation is best achieved using a _Calendar Table_, created and maintained in your environment. Searching for "SQL Calendar Table" should provide you with many potential starting points to build one that is appropriate for your business needs.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize you need to create a function to calculate the next business day from a given date.

```
create or replace function utl_next_business_day(date_in date default current_date)
returns date
language sql immutable leakproof strict
as $$
    with cd as (select  extract(isodow from date_in)::integer d)  
    select case when d between 1 and 4 
                then date_in + 1
                else date_in + 1 + (7-d) 
            end 
       from cd;       
$$; 

--- any single date 
select current_date, utl_next_business_day();

-- over time span (short)
select gdate::date for_date, utl_next_business_day(gdate::date) next_business_day
  from generate_series( current_date, current_date + 14, interval '1 day') gdate;

-- around year end over a time span
with test_date (dt) as
     ( values (date '2019-12-31')
            , (date '2020-12-31'), (date '2021-12-31'),(date '2022-12-31') 
            , (date '2021-01-01'), (date '2022-01-01'),(date '2023-01-01')
            )
select dt, utl_next_business_day(dt) from test_date
order by dt;
```

Alternatively with the calendar table suggestion from @Eric we get.

```
-- create and populate work table
create table bus_day_calendar ( bus_day date);
insert into bus_day_calendar (bus_day) 
  select utl_next_business_day(gdate::date)
    from generate_series( date '2018-12-31', date '2023-01-01', interval '1 day') gdate
   where extract(isodow from gdate)::integer not in (6,7) ;

--- Function to return next business day   
create or replace function utl_next_cal_business_day(date_in date default current_date)
returns date
language sql stable leakproof strict
as $$
    select min(bus_day)
      from bus_day_calendar 
     where bus_day > date_in;      
$$;    

--- any single date 
select current_date, utl_next_cal_business_day();

-- over time span (short)
select gdate::date for_date, utl_next_cal_business_day(gdate::date) next_business_day
  from generate_series( current_date, current_date + 14, interval '1 day') gdate;

-- around year end over a time span
with test_date (dt) as
     ( values (date '2019-12-31')
            , (date '2020-12-31'), (date '2021-12-31'),(date '2022-12-31') 
            , (date '2021-01-01'), (date '2022-01-01'),(date '2023-01-01')
            )
select dt, utl_next_cal_business_day(dt) from test_date
order by dt;
```

Neither of these as they currently stand handle a non-business day that falls on Mon-Fri, but both can be modified to do so. Since the calendar table requires only deleting roes I think that becomes the superior method if this is necessary.